# How to add textview for android image “viewer” app

Tags: textview, imageview

I'm new to Android app development and coding, I have learned how to make this app, but i would like to know how to add text to every image i will put in the activity?

Please help me :(

```
package com.imageviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int image_index = 0;
    private static final int MAX_IMAGE_COUNT = 3;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.raw.image1,
            R.raw.image2,
            R.raw.image3
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnPrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_btn);
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);       
        Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        showImage();        

    }

    private void showImage() {

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[image_index]);       

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case (R.id.previous_btn):

                image_index--;

                if (image_index == -1) {                    
                    image_index = MAX_IMAGE_COUNT - 1;                  
                }

                showImage();

            break;

            case (R.id.next_btn):

                image_index++;

                if (image_index == MAX_IMAGE_COUNT) {               
                image_index = 0;                
            }

                showImage();

            break;      

        }

    }
}
```

and this is the file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Previous"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous_btn" 
    android:text="Next"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/previous_btn"
    />         

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
package com.imageviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;    
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

         TextView txt;

    int image_index = 0;
    private static final int MAX_IMAGE_COUNT = 3;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.raw.image1,
            R.raw.image2,
            R.raw.image3
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnPrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous_btn);
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);       
        Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        showImage();        

    }

    private void showImage() {

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[image_index]);   
         txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myimage); 
          txt.setText("Your txt for the image");   

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case (R.id.previous_btn):

                image_index--;

                if (image_index == -1) {                    
                    image_index = MAX_IMAGE_COUNT - 1;                  
                }

                showImage();

            break;

            case (R.id.next_btn):

                image_index++;

                if (image_index == MAX_IMAGE_COUNT) {               
                image_index = 0;                
            }

                showImage();

            break;      

        }

    }
}
```

and for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Previous"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="124dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous_btn" 
    android:text="Next"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/previous_btn"
    />         

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myimageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myimageView"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="your text"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to and textview to your layout and align related your image and use it in your using id..